# No me carga la datagridview en algunas pc

Tags: vb

Hola alguien me podria ayudar, tengo una datagridview hecha en visual basic, la cual se debe mostrarme los datos obtenidos de una consulta, el problema que tengo es que en algunas pcs funciona en otras por alguna razon la tabla aparece sin datos, todas la pc obtienen la informacion de la misma base de datos, gracias

Comment: VB está un tanto obsoleto, podrías ver que características tiene el equipo en el que si te funciona, puede ser el tema de la transición a los 64 bits.

Comment: en mi caso todas las maquinas donde corre el programa tienen windows 10

Comment: y registraste las dll's en la carpeta SysWOW64?

Comment: no, disculpa, como se hace eso?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que VB es de 32 bits entonces las aplicaciones desarrolladas en el si quieres que funcionen deben ser registradas en las mencionada carpeta, la cual es una carpeta de compatibilidad para que sistemas de 64 bits puedan ejecutar determinadas aplicaciones de 32 bits

Comment: Para registrar las librerías debes usar regsvr32.exe

Comment: [Aqui](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-la-herramienta-regsvr32-y-solucionar-problemas-de-mensajes-de-error-de-regsvr32-a98d960a-7392-e6fe-d90a-3f4e0cb543e5) hay un enlace de Microsoft que te puede ayudar.